# pandas.DataFrame: Filter rows of df A based on data in df B?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

C = {'name': ['Alice', 'Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie'], 'phone': ['007', '1764', '1317210', '314159']}
CONTACTS = pd.DataFrame(data = C)

answer = {'guest_name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie'], 'attending': [True, False, True]}
guest_list = pd.DataFrame(data = answer)
```

---

**Illustrative context:**
I'm throwing a party, but there is a last-minute modification to the location. Thus, I want to call guests that said they will come.

I have two `pandas.DataFrame`:

1. my `CONTACTS`: with all my friends' name and phone. 
   Note that some friends (e.g. Alice) are listed twice if they have multiple phone numbers. This DataFrame is a constant and I cannot (or don't want to) modify it.
2. my `guest_list`: with all my friends' name and attending status (a boolean). 
   Note that, unlike in `CONTACTS`, friends name are listed here only once. All friends `name` listed in `CONTACTS` exist in `guest_list` and vice-versa (in other words, `CONTACTS.name` is surjective onto `guest_list.guest_name`).

**Problem:**
 I want to create the `attending_guests_contact` DataFrame containing the contact of my friends who attend the party only.

**Question:**
 ***How to get a subset of `CONTACTS` based on `answer.attending` boolean?***

Note that:

- I don't want to modify `CONTACTS`,
- I would prefer not to create a copy of `CONTACTS`, as I have 'a lot' of contacts (~10^3—10^4) and multiple parties thrown so it would be time and memory consuming (i.e. I would like to perform the sub-selection in line).

---

**Edit:** the two DataFrame don't share a same labeled column anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter `guest_list` by the column of Boolean values `attending`. Second check if the `attending` names from `guest_list` exist in `CONTACTS`

```
CONTACTS[CONTACTS.name.isin(guest_list.loc[guest_list.attending,'guest_name'])]

    name   phone
0    Alice     007
1    Alice    1764
3  Charlie  314159
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
attending_guests_contact = CONTACTS.merge(guest_list[guest_list.attending], \
                                          left_on="name", right_on="guest_name")

print attending_guests_contact

#       name   phone  attending
# 0    Alice     007       True
# 1    Alice    1764       True
# 2  Charlie  314159       True
```

This uses boolean indexing to filter `guest_list` to just the rows where `attending` is true, and then performs an inner join between `guest_list` and `CONTACTS` with [`.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).

Comment: @ebo no problem -- `.merge` allows you to specify `left_on` and `right_on` column names for the join logic. Please see my edits.